# Is it optional to include "at," as in "where are my keys at?" when you are asking where someone or something is?

Tags: prepositions

Would you tell me if it is optional to include *at* when you are asking where someone or something is? For example:

> Where are my keys (**at**)?
>
> I haven't seen Kate since the morning. Do you know where she is (**at**)?

Does the inclusion of *at* add anything in terms of meaning in the sentences above?

Comment: The interrogative adverb " where" means at /in/to  what place. When a question starts with " where", you can't use a preposition at the end of the sentence.

Comment: But l've heard many times native speakers use it.

Comment: It's used colloquially by some people, but it's not grammatical in any standard English as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Would I use it in formal writing: no.  But informally, yes, this is common in colloquial usage.  It doesn't change the meaning at all.